# Kubernetes Ingress Returning 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-pod

i have been setting up a K8s cluster and this is my config (below), and i have a problem with ingress returning 502 bad gateway.

I have everything green on my dashboard and i just cant figure out how the traffic is getting stuck in here.

All images (dockerfiles) work 100% locally.

I have looked through most of the similar questions here and i havent found the problem yet so thanks for your help in advance.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: moneyapi-deployment
  labels:
    app: moneyapi-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: moneyapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: moneyapi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: moneyapi
        image: money/api:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: projesecret
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: moneyfrontend-deployment
  labels:
    app: moneyfrontend-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: moneyfrontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: moneyfrontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: moneyfrontend
        image: money/frontend:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: projesecret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: moneyapiservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: moneyapi
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: moneyfrontendservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: moneyfrontend
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3030
    targetPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: moneyingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths: 
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: moneyapiservice
          servicePort: 8000
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: moneyfrontendservice
          servicePort: 3030
```

Comment: try adding a host to the ingress rules. Nginx doesn't support no host ingress, as far as i remember.

Comment: I already did that, and it was the same resilt

Comment: what are the logs saying?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/AlexandreLeitao/23a95fe7ebb12318659a02b4e1331bea

Comment: according your logs, it does the redirect correctly, but gets connection refused from the backend. Can you curl your services from within the cluster?

Comment: I tried the 2 pods and the ingress one and none of them have curl, so how do you suggest on doing this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208858/discussion-between-alexandre-leitao-and-suren).

Comment: `kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never curler --image viejo/curl -- curl your-service-name.namespace | IP_ADDRESS`. This is a curl image I have for testing purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Connection refused means the container is not listening on port 3000. Check the docker file of the image and maybe it's listening on some other port such as 80 or 8080. If that is the case then changing the targetPort of the service from 3000 to right port should make it work.